# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int' in the neural network

Tags: python

I am new man with data science. this is my coding for a new neural network. but, this bug has confused me a lot. Thanks for help

```py
def Conv_net(input_size=(None,None , 5)):
    num_encoder_tokens = 5
    num_decoder_tokens = 5
    latent_dim = 25
    # Define an input sequence and process it.
    encoder_1= Input(shape=(32, num_encoder_tokens))
    encoder_conv1d=Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', )(encoder_1)
    encoder_inputs=TimeDistributed(Dense(0))(encoder_conv1d)

    encoder = LSTM(1, return_state=True)
    encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
    # We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
    encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
    # Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
    decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_decoder_tokens))
    # We set up our decoder to return full output sequences,
    # and to return internal states as well. We don't use the
    # return states in the training model, but we will use them in inference.
    decoder_lstm = LSTM(1, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
    decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs, initial_state=encoder_states)
    decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
    decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
    # Define the model that will turn
    # `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
    model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
    # plot the model
    return model
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: ok.I already posted the Screenshot

Comment: Can you post the full error message? Which contains also the line where the error happens.

Comment: I have uploaded all the code to github. https://github.com/steinbergfu/1/blob/master/Welcome_To_Colaboratory.ipynb

Comment: @cnmcferren  hi, the information has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

this is the error message.I will delete it soon.thanks . [image]